# T-SQL File Stream Enable Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, file, stream

I am using T-SQL and Microsoft Management Studio 2008 R2. I want to create a database in which I can store video files.

After google search and some reading I have learned that there is a option to use "File Stream Enable Database". It was said that this kind of database should be used only when your files are larger then 2MB. I want to store video files, so I think this is suitable for my goals.

Please, give me more information about the main difference in using BLOB and FileStream Enable database or just to store the files in a given directory and to save only the url in the database table column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filestream was an interesting change when it came in for me; the bit that suprised me was Full Text Search was taken out of the operating system because it caused issues; but file stream put it back because Blobs caused issues.

Using Filestream is basically transparent to your application and it even backs the files up as if they were in the database - and thats the big benefit or cost over the save in database v save pointer in database.

You can insert files the same way as you did before and you can read them back in SQL in exactly the same way. The difference and benefit is that that SQL can take advantage of Windows system cache for reading and files saving its own resources to make other queries run quicker.

Answer (score 0):

> Please, give me more information about the main difference in using BLOB and FileStream Enable 
>   database

The feature you call for is "FileStream" not "FileStream enable".

Some blogs are also around, like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rdoherty/archive/2007/10/12/getting-traction-with-sql-server-2008-filestream.aspx

At kleast try reading the documentation before running around and have other people do your basic groundwork.